# Hex file converter

Tags: c#, optimization, memory-management, converting

I have written a C# file reader that reads a file converts the bytes of the file to hex and writes it out to another file. It works fine but it takes 7.2GB of memory when converting a 300MB file.

What can I do to this code to make it take less memory?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Hex__Reader
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            OpenFile();
        }

        private static void OpenFile()
        {
            uint j = 0;
            byte[] bytes = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(filename);
            char[] hex = BitConverter.ToString(bytes).Replace("-", " ").ToCharArray();
            //char[] hexchar = hex.ToCharArray();
            System.IO.StreamWriter writer = new System.IO.StreamWriter(filename,false);
            Console.WriteLine("Writing Bytes");
            for (uint i = 0; i < hex.Length; i++)
            {
                if (j == 50)
                {
                    writer.WriteLine();
                    writer.WriteLine();
                    j = 0;
                }
                else
                {
                    writer.Write(hex[i]);
                    j++;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your problem is that you load the whole file into memory, convert each byte to three characters (that's the file size times 6), going through `Replace` and `ToCharArray`.

To avoid holding all in memory, you should *stream* the data, converting and writing *each chunk*. This way, you'll only hold a fraction of the file at each time:

```
using (System.IO.StreamWriter writer = new System.IO.StreamWriter(filename,false)) {
    using (FileStream fs = File.OpenRead(filename)) 
    {
        byte[] b = new byte[50];

        while (fs.Read(b,0,b.Length) > 0) 
        {
            writer.WriteLine(BitConverter.ToString(bytes).Replace("-", " "));
        }
    }
}
```

---

If (even when the buffer size is more optimal at 1024) you still have memory issues, it might be because of `BitConverter.ToString(bytes).Replace("-", " ")`... you could use some other methods to make to conversion, as suggested [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/3928b8cb-3703-4672-8ccd-33718148d1e3/byte-array-to-hex-string?forum=csharpgeneral), for example:

```
int itemsInLineCounter = 0;
using (System.IO.StreamWriter writer = new System.IO.StreamWriter(filename,false)) {
    using (FileStream fs = File.OpenRead(filename)) {
        byte[] b = new byte[1024];
        int read;

        while ((read = fs.Read(b,0,b.Length)) > 0) {
            for (int i = 0; i < read; i++) {
                writer.Write(bytes[i].ToString("X2"));
                if (itemsInLineCounter > NUM_OF_ITEMS_IN_LINE) {
                    writer.WriteLine();
                    itemsInLineCounter = 0;
                } else {
                    writer.Write(' ');
                    itemsInLineCounter++;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: it uses more memory now and it also takes longer

Comment: hmm... the buffer size is not optimal... try using buffer size 1024...

Comment: added some other options

Comment: Another option, which should create fewer temporary/short strings, would be to expand line-sized chunks of text from `bytes` into a StringBuilder.

Comment: Down To 320MB Now

Answer (score 4):

If you're interested in further optimization, this should maintain a minimal memory footprint and be about 25% faster:

```
    private static void OpenFile()
    {
        string[] digits = new string[] { "0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F" };
        using(System.IO.BinaryReader br = new System.IO.BinaryReader
            (new System.IO.FileStream
                (
                "ByteFile.dat", 
                System.IO.FileMode.Open, 
                System.IO.FileAccess.Read, 
                System.IO.FileShare.None, 
                1024)
                )
                )
        {
            using(System.IO.StreamWriter sw = new System.IO.StreamWriter("HexFile.txt"))
            {
                byte[] inbuff = new byte[0];
                int b = 0;
                while((inbuff = br.ReadBytes(50)).Length > 0)
                {
                    for(b = 0; b < inbuff.Length - 1; b++)
                    {
                        sw.Write(digits[(inbuff[b] / 16) % 16] + digits[inbuff[b] % 16] + " ");
                    }
                    sw.WriteLine(digits[(inbuff[b] / 16) % 16] + digits[inbuff[b] % 16]);

                }
            }
        }
    }
```

You'll notice that using a string array as a look up table for the hex digits eliminates any tostring conversions.